# Applying same expression for each item in an array if the type is array

Tags: c#

I would like to apply a filter condition on a JSON object

So, I create an expression tree to visit the JSON node by name, then apply conversion/parsing and `BinaryOperation` on it.

```
var stuff = JObject.Parse("{ 'Name': 'Jon Smith', 'Address': { 'City': 'New York', 'State': 'NY' },  'Tags': ['Developer', 'Scrum Master'], 'Age': 42,  }");

var leftExpressionTree = GetLeftExpressionTree("Name", stuff)

var binaryExpression = DoExpression(leftExpressionTree, "Jon Smith", ExpressionType.Equal)

//Complie and execute expression

public static Expression DoExpression(Expression leftExpression, string rightOperandStr, ExpressionType expressionType)
{
    var leftExpressionConversionfromJtokenToString = Expression.Convert(leftExpression, typeof(string));         
    var rightExpression = Expression.Call(GetParseMethodForType(rightOperandStr), Expression.Constant(rightOperandStr));
    var binaryExpression = Expression.MakeBinary(expressionType, leftExpressionConversionfromJtokenToString, rightExpression);        
    return binaryExpression;
}
```

That is ok, "Name" is a string type and it works

However there is an issue when I do the following:

```
var leftExpressionTree = GetLeftExpressionTree("Tags")

var binaryExpression = DoExpression(leftExpressionTree, "Scrum Master", ExpressionType.Equal)
```

This does not work because the Tags is a `JArray`.

The expected behaviour when it is an `array` is, the condition have to be applied on all array items and any of it is true the filter will pass

So whatever code written in `DoExpression` have to be executed for every item in the array.

How could I do this? Note that I simplified the `DoExpression()` function for the matter of simplicity, there are more checks and conditions in the actual function.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did this. Changed DoExpression to a funcion returning result as opposed to an Expression

```
 public static bool DoAction(JToken token, string rightOperand, ExpressionType type)
 {
    var str = (string) token;
    var tokenExpr = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object));
    var strExpr = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object));
    var expr = Expression.MakeBinary(type, tokenExpr, strExpr);
    var compiledExpr = Expression.Lambda<Func<object, object, bool>>(expr, tokenExpr, strExpr).Compile();
    return compiledExpr(str, rightOperand);

  }
```

A function which calls enumerable "Any" on object(JArray)

```
  public static Expression GetArrayExpression(Expression leftExpression)
   {
    Type predType = typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(typeof(JToken), typeof(bool));

    MethodInfo anyMethod = (MethodInfo)GetGenericMethod(typeof(Enumerable), "Any", new[] { typeof(JToken) }, new[] { typeof(JArray), predType }, BindingFlags.Static);

    MethodInfo miDoAction = typeof(Program).GetMethod("DoAction", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);

    ParameterExpression p = Expression.Parameter(typeof(JToken), "item");

    var callExpr1 = Expression.Lambda<Func<JToken, bool>>(Expression.Call(miDoAction, p, Expression.Constant("SearchForThis"), Expression.Constant(ExpressionType.Equal)), p);
    var callExpr = Expression.Call(anyMethod, leftExpression, callExpr1);

    return callExpr;

   }
```

A function which call the function if it is an object

```
  public static Expression GetObjectExpression(Expression leftExpression)
     {
            MethodInfo miDoAction = typeof(Program).GetMethod("DoAction", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
            var callExpr = Expression.Call(miDoAction, leftExpression, Expression.Constant("SearchForThis"), Expression.Constant(ExpressionType.Equal));

            return callExpr;
     }
```

Then it is just a matter of a conditional call

```
 Expression leftExpression;

       var isTypeJarray = Expression.TypeIs(leftExpression, typeof(JArray));

      return Expression.Condition(isTypeJarray, GetArrayExpression(leftExpression), GetObjectExpression(leftExpression));
```